# Dynamically Update Office References in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have some access databases (executed via runtime) that are using Office 2010 x86.  We will be upgrading to Office 2013 x64 and the upgrade process is causing the errors since the .accdb file references the Excel and Outlook 14 libraries. I am looking for a way to dynamically update the reference via vba on db open.  Does anyone know if I can do this on a system using the access runtime?  I think I can use the References.IsBroken method and AddFromFile or AddFromGUID to do the update.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you can't update the references on the fly from the runtime.

Mixing Office versions can cause lots of headaches, especially when mixing 32/64 bits versions of Office. You should convert each of your database to Access 2013 (if that's what you will be using on all machines) once and switch to using the Access 2013 runtime.